# java.io.Exception: cannot run program "wsimport"; error=11, Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client, wsimport

I need to generate **WebService Client code** for almost **1500 WSDL files daily**. It will be a job  which will run daily for these files.
I tried this through java code. What I have done is:

I took all the WSDL files as an file array and ran wsimport commad through **Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wsimport command")** for that file array using **For** loop. But Its giving me below error:

**java.io.Exception: cannot run program "wsimport"; error=11, Resource temporarily unavailable**

After getting this error I tried giving **waitFor()** to execute one commad at a time, code ran fine but it took almost 6 hrs to generate ClientCode for all WSDLs. We can't wait for this much time daily, so need to optimize the time of this Job.

What will the best way to do it?

Comment: Did you try using Axis instead of wsimport? which has some flexible options to create client code.

Comment: No...I am very new to WebService so do not have much idea...will try with that...any quick tutorial link which can be of help?

Comment: This may help - https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html